# Setting up expression for distance of random point to origin

Tags: probability, random-variables, density-function

> **Problem Statement:**
>
> Suppose that the coordinates of a point $(X, Y)$ are such that
>   $X ∼ U[0, 1)$ and $Y ∼ U[0, 1)$
>   Compute the probability that the distance
>   from this point to the origin is less than or equal to L. You should consider the two cases when
>
> $0 \leq L \leq 1$ and $1 \leq L \leq \sqrt{2}$

I'm having troubles just trying to set up the density function here because there are so many inequalities. I'm new to stats so this might just be an easy problem that I didn't see

Comment: The distance of a point $(X,Y)$  to the origin is $\sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}$. By the way, it could help to draw a diagram of the sample space and  the region where the distance to the origin is $\leq L$. The picture will look a bit different in each of the two cases of $L$.

Comment: Yes that is simple and I already got that. What I'm having troubles is putting all those inequalities together

Comment: Maybe draw a picture? $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed over the unit square, so $P(d((X,Y),(0,0))<L)$ is the area of the intersection of the circle of radius $L$ with that square. When $L\le 1$, the region is just a quarter circle whose area is easy to calculate. When $1\le L\le \sqrt{2}$, you should be able to describe the boundaries of the figure and therefore set up and integration. In short, do not worry so much about manipulating inequalities, draw a picture instead.

Comment: You need to know the correlation between $X$ and $Y$ to set up the joint density function.